# hard code large hex value throws error in C#

Tags: c#

ulong va = 0xffffffe0‬;

This throws the below errors:

```
Error   1   Unexpected character '‬'    
Error   2   Invalid expression term ''  
Error   3   ; expected  
Error   4   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

why is it so? How can i fix?

Comment: it seems like a non printable character in your source code; I would suggest to delete the line and type it again.

Comment: Char code `8236` hiding between the `0` and the `;`

Comment: i copied/pasted in notepad++ and turned ON the symbol display and i dont see any invalid character.

Comment: Which would say the offending character displays as zero width character on your system.  There are unicode characters that have no visible aspect (they're supposed to modify others, but if what they are supposed to modify isn't there they don't show up at all.  There also are unassigned values.)  Erase the offending material and retype.  (getting rid of the e0; should be enough.)

Answer (score 1):

I've copy/pasted your line in notepad2mod and you have an incorrect character here:

```
ulong va = 0xffffffe0?;
---------------------^
```

Remove it or use what is below and copy/paste it again in your editor.

```
ulong va = 0xffffffe0;
```

Comment: thats not case , i have checked

Comment: If you remove the `?` here and use `ulong va = 0xffffffe0;` it works as expected.

Comment: but in the notepad to me , it does not show that question mark.

Comment: sorry, i forgot i use notepad2mod. answer updated.

Comment: ok, so when i copy pasted your code, that fixed that error.

Answer (score 0):

When I cut and paste it into something so I can actually view the encoding I find there's a 2C20 character which appears to be "Glagolitic Capital Letter Yeri".  Obviously your system displays this as nothing.